# Nodejs not always showing errors

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, bcrypt

I'm starting to learn js and nodejs. I had an issue which took me a long time to resolve.

I was using bcrypt library and i made a typo on require statemant:

`const bcrpyt = require('bcryptjs');`

then on my pre save schema i used:

```
bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
    user.password = hash;
    next();
});
```

so `bcrypt` was `undefined`

on my route I had:

```
user.save()
    .then(/*some action*/)
    .catch(e => res.status(400).send(e));
```

so after making a request, I got status 400 but `e` was empty object `{}`

Any idea why there was no error such as "calling hash on undefined" or something like that?

Comment: have you tried `console.log(e)` ?  Do you get the same thing?

Comment: Did you try `throw`ing the `err` of `bycrypt.hash` if there is any?

Comment: @boyd omg `console.log(e)` shows exactly the error. I thought `send(e)` would show the same which was clearly an mistake... Thanks. Is there any configuration on node to set to show such errors on response?

@imans77 `bcrypt.hash` didn't give any error because it wasn't even executed due to a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send only the message to the client:

`res.status(400).send(e.message)`

I don't  know if you are using express.js or plain node.js but if you want to see these errors on the client side you can wrap the entire server request code in a try catch block like so(using vanilla nodejs):

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    try{
        response.writeContinue(undefinedVariable);
    }catch (error) {
        response.status(400).end(error.message);
    }
}).listen(port);
```